# in nested UIStackView when I add more than one arranged subview, it breaks the layout, why?

Tags: ios, uikit, uistackview

Playing with UIStackView I encountered a weird issue which does not allow me to add extra arranged subview in nested UIStackView:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let subViews = [UIColor.gray, UIColor.darkGray, UIColor.lightGray].map { (color) -> UIView in
            let v = UIView()
            v.backgroundColor = color
            return v
        }

        let redView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: subViews)
        redView.distribution = .fillEqually
        redView.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 100).isActive = true


        let blueView = UIView()
        blueView.backgroundColor = .blue


        let buttons = [UIColor.gray, UIColor.darkGray, UIColor.lightGray].map { (color) -> UIView in
            let v = UIView()
            v.backgroundColor = color
            return v
        }

        let buttonsView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: buttons)
        buttonsView.distribution = .fillEqually
        buttonsView.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 100).isActive = true


        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [redView, blueView, buttonsView])

        view.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.fillSuperview()

    }
```

In result, I get full-stretched blue view instead of expecting behavior:

[image]

But when I leaving ONE subview in bottom stack view - it appears as expected

```
   let buttons = [UIColor.gray].map { (color) -> UIView in
        let v = UIView()
        v.backgroundColor = color
        return v
    }

    let buttonsView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: buttons)
    buttonsView.distribution = .fillEqually
    buttonsView.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 100).isActive = true


    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [redView, blueView, buttonsView])
```

[image]

why ? What is wrong with the code ? Any help or hint is appreciated, I tried `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` on top and bottom stack views as well but without any luck

Comment: set Alignment and Distribution to parent stackview and u should call translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false  to buttonsview,redview

Comment: thanks for the help, tried that but I need to get middle view stretched and top and bottom views to be fixed, so distribution unfortunately doesn't help

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: desired output is the same as in the last screenshot, but instead of one grey view in the bottom, I would like to get three subviews arranged as in the top stack view

Comment: check with buttonsView.axis = .horizontal

Comment: and redView.axis = .horizontal,stackview.alignment = .fill, stackview.distribution = .fill

Comment: thanks so much for the help, you helped me to get on the track the issue was `buttonsView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true` instead of lessThanOrEqualToConstant !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the bottom stackview it was required to set 
`buttonView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true`

instead of

`buttonView.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 100).isActive = true`